# MVC - Catching a navigation request on the site controller before the LayOut controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

At my company we are discussing wether or not to got and make our next web app in MVC. 
I have been charged to figure out some basic stuff which could stop us dead in our tracks, and so have spend some time figureing out the MVC platform as best i could.

There is however one thing im wondering, is it possible, and if so how - to have a menu made on the _LayOut page/controller, which when a user presses a menu navigation i am able to catch on the specfic page before it goes to the layout controller?

***UPDATED*** I forgot to mention that i want to be able to save a form depending on what site i am on. So i may have 10 pages with different forms and depending on which one of these i am on, i have to save the form on that page using the same link in my menu.

My explaning might be abit off so ill quickly describe the scenario and maybe there is another way of doing this.

The user is filling out alot of data on the page, they then press the navigation menu to go to a new page, i want to save the entered data before navigating to the next page for them.

Sorry for my bad english it is not my primary language.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I dont think this is an MVC specific problem. I imagine your previous webforms? solution effectively submitted the whole page state on any 'click'. you can do this in MVC too, but its something microsoft mived away from because of its downsides

Answer (score 2):

A way to do what you're looking for is to attach a client-side event handler which submits the data before navigating to a new page. It would look something like this:

```
$(".navigation a").click(function (event) {
    // Get form data, process it and POST/PUT/DELETE
});
```

If you're supporting modern browsers then you can subscribe to the input event of your form and attach yourself on the before unload if anything in your form has changed since the window was loaded as suggested in one of the comments. If you need to support older browsers as well subscribe to the change event of the input fields in the form in order to attach the handler for `beforeunload`.

```
form.oninput = function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = submitFormData;
};

function submitFormData() {
    // Gather and submit your data
}
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin and thanks for the quick answer.
I can image how the first example would work, however i was wondering if you could come up with a example for the latter one? even if its psudo.

Comment: @MichaelA I removed the second one. I didn't think of the fact that the anchors cannot perform a POST to your controller, thus the second suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: I image that you would at least want to display a 'confirm save' message before actually saving the data - what if the user entered incorrect data and just wanted to abandon it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That would be a requriment yes :)

Comment: you can also catch the page close event. which alot of sites do despite the ui limitations (try editing and navigate before submit!)